# Bash alias for string variable/copy by reference instead of value

Tags: bash, variables

Consider the following Bash script:

`$ A=35

$ echo $A

35

$ B=$A

$ echo $B

35

$ B=43

$ echo $B

43

$ echo $A

35`

I declared a variable `A`, assigned the value `35` to it, made `B` equal to `A`, and assigned the value `43` to `B`.  It appears that `A` retains the value `35` after all this, so I'm guessing when you assign one variable in bash to another, it's copy by value, not copy by reference.

What I want to be able to do is change `B`'s value and have it reflected in `A` (copy by reference).  Or, in my real case, I simply don't want to incur the memory overhead of copy by value, as I know it's a large variable and don't want to store it twice in memory.  Is there a way to do this in Bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference another variable with

```
$ a=42
$ reference=a
$ echo ${!reference}
42
```

To change the value of the referenced variable

```
$ eval ${reference}=4
$ echo ${!reference}
4
echo $a
4
```

Comment: is there a way to assign variable B as being a reference to varaible A, so you only have to think about the referential nature at the point of assignment, rather than later on when you're using and/or modifying B?

Comment: @BryceThomas Unfortunately, no. This is how indirection in `bash` works. In `ksh`, indirection works by means of `namerefs` (`typeset -n`) which work the way you describe.